# typedef in a class- C++

Tags: c++

What difference do A and B make in the main program?

> A)
>
> ```
> #include<iostream>
> class Base
> {
>     typedef int index;
> public:
>     index i;
> };
>
>
> B)
>
> #include<iostream>
> class Base
> {
>     public:
>     typedef int index;
>     index i;
> };
> ```

Comment: What difference do you think it would make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the former, only members of Base can use the typedef Index. In the latter, everyone can use the typedef by saying Base::Index.

Answer (score 2):

Access type is by default private with classes (structs defaults to public) meaning that your typedef is not available from child classes (derived classes) or outside of the class (can only be used inside the class itself). B declares it public meaning it can be used from anywhere.